# Coq Vector explode in proof mode?

Tags: coq

A bit of a mechanical question regarding Coq Vectors.
In my proof I have

```
input: Vector.t nat 1
==================================
compliacted_fixpoint_for input = true
```

I am looking for a theorem/tactic that can explode the vector so I can rewrite with the inner nat, like below, so I can then use `cbn`.

```
input: Vector.t nat 1
n: nat
Hin: input = [n]
==================================
complicated_fixpoint_for [n] = true
```

`inversion input` does  introduce `n: nat` but surprisingly not `Hin`, which does not help me call `cbn` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `rewrite (eta input).`

Here are two lemmas that can be useful:

```
Import VectorNotations.

Lemma vec0 {T}: forall (v:Vector.t T 0), v = [].
  apply (case0 (fun x => x=[])).
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma vec1 {T} : forall (v:Vector.t T 1), v = [hd v].
  intros.
  rewrite (VectorSpec.eta v).
  apply f_equal.
  apply vec0.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dependent inversion input.`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.dependent-inversion) instead.
When the thing you want to invert is a term that appears in the goal, rather than just a proof/hypothesis, you want to use `dependent inversion`.